# Как заменить нужные буквы при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: html, css, музыка

Ребята такой вопрос. Я создаю сайт для музыкантов и нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку с нужной им тональностью менялись только аккорды а не весь текст как это сделать ? Спасибо заранее

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я в аккордах вообще не разбираюсь, но если вам надо выполнить замену в тексте — лучший вариант [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).